# How to specify alignment in specific cell in tables?

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I have a table with solutions from statistic tests and I am needed to have numbers such as 1234^{***}. How to align such number with usual one: 1234, that way it is right aligned to its numbers, and not how i got in example I am gonna show here. 
Here is my code:

```
  \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccr}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
   \parbox[m]{2.5cm} {Simbol \\kriptovalute} & $\alpha$ & $t-test_\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $t-test_\beta$ \\
    \midrule
     BTC  & 0.0000 & -0.072 & 1.000 & $575.256^{***}$ \\
     XRP  & 0.0003 & 0.040 & 1.263 & 8.213 \\
   ETH   & -0.0002 & -0.028 & 0.975 & 8.739 \\
    BCH   & 0.0017 & 0.226 & 0.999 & 6.779 \\
    EOS  & -0.0064 & -0.747 & 1.141 & 6.868 \\
     USDT & -0.0005 & -0.552 & -0.013 & -0.789 \\
   XLM   & -0.0068 & -0.763 & 1.200 & 6.947 \\
     LTC  & -0.0044 & -0.687 & 1.120 & 9.039 \\
    TRX  & -0.0141 & -1.473 & 1.713 & 9.169 \\
     MIOTA  & -0.0101 & -1.008 & 1.093 & 5.591 \\
     BNB  & -0.0022 & -0.289 & 1.296 & 8.864 \\
    XMR  & 0.0667 & 1.513 & -0.463 & -0.538 \\
    DASH & 0.0034 & 0.722 & 0.970 & 10.607 \\
    ETC   & -0.0003 & -0.038 & 1.147 & 8.001\\
     ZEC  & -0.0025 & -0.450 & 1.035 & 9.589 \\
     \bottomrule[1.5pt]
   \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
```

[image]

First row, last column doesn't look right. Does anybody have an advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.4]SSS}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
   {\parbox[m]{2.5cm} {Simbol \\kriptovalute}} & {$\alpha$} & {$t-\text{test}_\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$t-\text{test}_\beta$} \\
    \midrule
     BTC  & 0.0000 & -0.072 & 1.000 & 575.256\textsuperscript{***} \\
     XRP  & 0.0003 & 0.040 & 1.263 & 8.213 \\
   ETH   & -0.0002 & -0.028 & 0.975 & 8.739 \\
    BCH   & 0.0017 & 0.226 & 0.999 & 6.779 \\
    EOS  & -0.0064 & -0.747 & 1.141 & 6.868 \\
     USDT & -0.0005 & -0.552 & -0.013 & -0.789 \\
   XLM   & -0.0068 & -0.763 & 1.200 & 6.947 \\
     LTC  & -0.0044 & -0.687 & 1.120 & 9.039 \\
    TRX  & -0.0141 & -1.473 & 1.713 & 9.169 \\
     MIOTA  & -0.0101 & -1.008 & 1.093 & 5.591 \\
     BNB  & -0.0022 & -0.289 & 1.296 & 8.864 \\
    XMR  & 0.0667 & 1.513 & -0.463 & -0.538 \\
    DASH & 0.0034 & 0.722 & 0.970 & 10.607 \\
    ETC   & -0.0003 & -0.038 & 1.147 & 8.001\\
     ZEC  & -0.0025 & -0.450 & 1.035 & 9.589 \\
     \bottomrule[1.5pt]
   \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can still be improved. Any suggestions welcome.